# Minimum number of operations required

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures

I came across this question in recent interview :

Given an array of integers and an integer k. You can perform operations any number of times(may be zero) on any number of elements in an array :

If number is divisible by k, divide it by k (you are not allowed to multiply it by k if it is divisible)

If number is not divisible by k, multiply it by k

You need to update this array in such a way that difference between maximum and minimum number in an array is minimum and find minimum number of operations to do so.

e.g. Let a[5] = {82, 79, 38, 49, 9} and k=5, we apply 2nd operation on last element. Now, a[5] = {82, 79, 38, 49, 9*5} and this updated array gives minimum difference between minimum and maximum numbers i.e. max - min = 82 - 38 = 44

I am thinking about applying recursive solution fixing one number and trying to keep all numbers as close as fixed number.

But need better approach to solve this problem efficiently.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only decrease the difference by applying ops on the maximum / minimum number. I think you just have to keep trying to apply on max/min as long as a move can decrease the total range. Obviously you have to recompute the max and mins as you go. Each element only has a constant number of moves so `O(NlogN)` with a BST is doable. There's probably an `O(N)` way I'm missing though

Comment: are the numbers always positive?

Comment: Yes, all numbers are positive

Comment: @Primusa That is not necessarily true, e.g. `items = [14, 2, 20]` and `k = 2`, you have to act on both `14` and `20`, but only `20` is an extrema. You cannot decide what to do with `14` until you actually see the `2`, so I do not think `O(N)` is possible.

Comment: @norok2 20 -> 10 then 14 becomes the extrema. Another idea would be to write out each possibility for each item. I guess there are O(NlogN) total possibilities so that may be a bound

Comment: By the time you see the `20` you have *lost* your `O(N)` chance of modifying `14`.

Comment: @Primusa what do you mean with *"Each element only has a constant number of moves"*, multiply by `k` can be done infinitely many times, unless after first `k` multiplication it is considered divisible by `k`. In any case, in my example from above, `14` can be divided by `2` once, `2` once, but `20` twice...

Comment: @norok2 "If number is divisible by k, divide it by k (you are not allowed to multiply it by k if it is divisible)" Technically you can divide by `K` logN number of times but assuming that the inputs are ints so it's practically constant

Comment: To be clear, after applying 2nd operation on a number, next time, only 1st operation can be applied to it as it is divisible by k now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is doable in `O(NlogN)`. For each element we can write out every element it can transform into. So let each element transform into a list of candidate elements it can become. The problem now becomes [smallest range covering elements from k lists](https://leetcode.com/problems/smallest-range-covering-elements-from-k-lists/) which can be done in `O(NlogN)`.

A really simple way to solve the smallest range problem:

1. Merge the elements from each list into one list, keep track of the list that each element came from
2. Run a sliding window over the merged list that has one element from each sublist
3. Take candidate ranges

The following is my solution to the smallest range problem. You just need some boilerplate code to transform your list of integers into a list of lists.

```py
from collections import deque, Counter

class Solution:
    def smallestRange(self, nums: List[List[int]]) -> List[int]:

        new = []
        # merge each list and keep track of original list
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in nums[i]:
                new.append((j, i))
        # sort so each sliding window represents a range
        new.sort()

        d = deque()
        c = Counter()

        res = [-float('inf'), float('inf')]
        # iterate over sliding windows that contain each list
        for i in new:
            d.append(i)
            c[i[1]] += 1
            while len(c) == len(nums):
                res = min(res, [d[0][0], d[-1][0]], key = lambda x: x[1] - x[0])
                a, b = d.popleft()
                c[b] -= 1
                if not c[b]: del c[b]
        return res
```

Comment: @גלעדברקן You're right, but I'm assuming that every element is an integer so i'm just letting logm be bounded by 32

Comment: I think this is correct, however, you are missing the step to `find minimum number of operations`, however, should be a simple modification from your current solution.